# How to show/hide a UIView with animation in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview, uiviewanimationtransition

The main UIView contains two subviews - `UIView_1` and `UIView_2`.
In the `UIView_2`, there is a button to show or hide the `UIView_1`.
For example, when a user touches the button to show the `UIView_1`, then **`UIView_1` will slide down and `UIView_2` will push downwards with transition**.
I have very little knowledge in animation. Can someone show me some sample code for reference?
Should I use CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation?
Thanks.[image]

Comment: Answer for this question can be found easily by stumbling in stack overflow. Not merely a question or an issue.. Please use papa google once before posting.

Comment: @Anil This question is rather old ;) I guess it was a legitimate (non-duplicate) question back in 2011 ;)

Comment: Oops.. Missed date there.. My bad!!!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't need anything so complex. Just change the view's frame size.

```
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = /* determine length of animation */;
    CGRect newFrameSize = /* determine what the frame size should be */;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    theViewToChange.frame = newFrameSize;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 7):

Simply Hide/show with fadein/out effect
`

/*To Show*/

```
sliderView.hidden = NO;
sliderView.alpha = 0.1;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    sliderView.alpha = 1.0f;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // do some
}];
```

/*To hide*/

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    sliderView.frame =  CGRectMake(130, 30, 0, 0);
    [sliderView setAlpha:0.1f];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    sliderView.hidden = YES;
}];
```

`

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to do with `UIView_2`.

1. Place `UIView_1` below `UIView_2` in Interface Builder.
2. Size `UIView_2` to take up all the space below the `UINavigationBar`.
3. Use the following code to either resize (using `uiview2_resized_rect`) the frame for `UIView_2`, or translate/move the frame for `UIView_2` (using `uiview2_translated_rect` ):

```
CGRect uiview1_original_rect = UIView_1.frame;
CGRect uiview2_original_rect = UIView_2.frame;
```

CGRect uiview2_translated_rect = CGRectMake(uiview2_original_rect.origin.x, 
        uiview2_original_rect.origin.y+uiview1_original_rect.size.height, 
        uiview2_original_rect.size.width, 
        uiview2_original_rect.size.height);

CGRect uiview2_resized_rect = CGRectMake(uiview2_original_rect.origin.x, 
    uiview2_original_rect.origin.y+uiview1_original_rect.size.height, 
    uiview2_original_rect.size.width, 
    uiview2_original_rect.size.height-uiview1_original_rect.size.height);

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.300 delay:0.0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut|UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState 
                 animations:^{
    //uncomment this and comment out the other if you want to move UIView_2 down to show UIView_1
    //UIView_2.frame = uiview2_translated_rect;
    UIView_2.frame = uiview2_resized_rect;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];